# How to write query for desired result

Tags: mysql

In my table there is 4 column:

```
id, mobileno(msisdn),type,date
```

now I want to make one report such as

```
**date ,         msisdn ,    count**
  
1-oct-2020 , 9999999999    12
1-oct-2020 , 9999999888    10
1-oct-2020 , 9999999666    10

2-oct-2020 , 9999999999    4
2-oct-2020 , 9999999888    30
2-oct-2020 , 9999999666    1
```

This is how I want it.
second report like:

```
msisdn, unique date()

ex:
msisdn    1oct.  2oct.   3oct   4oct.  5 oct and ............. 31oct
99998877   12 ,  2,       4,     44,     13,    ................ 32
99998874  12 ,  2,       4,     44,     13,    ................ 32
99998875   12 ,  2,       4,     44,     13,    ................ 32
```

Sample data screenshot is attached [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *in my table there is 4 column* Provide it as CREATE TABLE script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping and counting:

```sql
SELECT `date`, `msisdn`, count(1) as `count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`, `msisdn`
ORDER BY `date` ASC, `msisdn`ASC;
```

Comment: thnx @mwienhold
can you please guide me one more query 

i need to find one more report 

now i want 

msisdn, unique date()

ex:
msisdn         1oct.  2oct.   3oct   4oct.  5 oct and ............. 31oct
99998877     12 ,    2,        4,     44,        13,    .................... 32
99998874    12 ,    2,        4,     44,        13,    .................... 32


like this

Comment: @HouseOfBlogger take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399 If you have a new requirement you can ask a new question.